# Can't edit repeat events after upgrade to 5.22

Tags: repeating-events

Wordpress 4.9

Prior to upgrade, when editing repeat event the prompt (popup) on saving offered three choices:

1 Only this event
All others in the series will remain unchanged.

2 This event onwards
Change applies to this event and all that come after it.

3 Every event
Change applies to every event in the series.

After the upgrade only one choice is offered:

1 Only this event
All others in the series will remain unchanged.

It works fine in sandbox but that's running 5.4 alpha.
Is that safe to upgrade to?

Answer (score 2):

I can see at 5.2.2(D7) all three options when a repeated event is edited.

[image]

I believe there is no special condition that will hide other 2 fields. Can you check browser console if they are hidden? It might be because of theme.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep I turned on browser console and tried again and the other 2 fields appeared. The only thing I'd done in the interim was flush caches? Maybe that fixed it who knows!

Comment: Yes, most probably it may be because of cache.